# WebGL. Full screen quad or triangle for invoking fragment shader for every pixel?

Tags: javascript, webgl, fragment-shader

In many examples over internet (such as [webglfundamentals](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-image-processing.html) or [webgl-bolerplate](https://github.com/paulirish/webgl-boilerplate/blob/master/index.html)) authors used two triangles to cover full screen and invoke pixel shader for every pixel on canvas.

```js
var canvas, gl, buffer, 
       vertex_shader, fragment_shader, 
       currentProgram, vertex_position,
       timeLocation, resolutionLocation,
       parameters = {  start_time  : new Date().getTime(), 
                       time        : 0, 
                       screenWidth : 0, 
                       screenHeight: 0 };
   init();
   animate();
 
   function init() {
    vertex_shader = document.getElementById('vs').textContent;
    fragment_shader = document.getElementById('fs').textContent;
    canvas = document.querySelector( 'canvas' );
    try {
     gl = canvas.getContext( 'experimental-webgl' );
    } catch( error ) { }
    if ( !gl ) 
     throw "cannot create webgl context";

    // Create Vertex buffer (2 triangles)
    buffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer );
    gl.bufferData( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array( [ - 1.0, - 1.0, 1.0, - 1.0, - 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, - 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, - 1.0, 1.0 ] ), gl.STATIC_DRAW );
 
    currentProgram = createProgram( vertex_shader, fragment_shader );
    timeLocation = gl.getUniformLocation( currentProgram, 'time' );
    resolutionLocation = gl.getUniformLocation( currentProgram, 'resolution' );
   }
 
   function createProgram( vertex, fragment ) {
    var program = gl.createProgram();
    var vs = createShader( vertex, gl.VERTEX_SHADER );
    var fs = createShader( '#ifdef GL_ES\nprecision highp float;\n#endif\n\n' + fragment, gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER );
 
    if ( vs == null || fs == null ) 
            return null;
 
    gl.attachShader( program, vs );
    gl.attachShader( program, fs );
    gl.deleteShader( vs );
    gl.deleteShader( fs );
    gl.linkProgram( program );
 
    if ( !gl.getProgramParameter( program, gl.LINK_STATUS ) ) {
     alert( "ERROR:\n" +
     "VALIDATE_STATUS: " + gl.getProgramParameter( program, gl.VALIDATE_STATUS ) + "\n" +
     "ERROR: " + gl.getError() + "\n\n" +
     "- Vertex Shader -\n" + vertex + "\n\n" +
     "- Fragment Shader -\n" + fragment );
     return null;
    }
    return program;
   }
 
   function createShader( src, type ) {
    var shader = gl.createShader( type );
    gl.shaderSource( shader, src );
    gl.compileShader( shader );
    if ( !gl.getShaderParameter( shader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS ) ) {
     alert( ( type == gl.VERTEX_SHADER ? "VERTEX" : "FRAGMENT" ) + " SHADER:\n" + gl.getShaderInfoLog( shader ) );
     return null;
    }
    return shader;
   }
 
   function resizeCanvas( event ) {
    if ( canvas.width != canvas.clientWidth ||
      canvas.height != canvas.clientHeight ) {
     canvas.width = canvas.clientWidth;
     canvas.height = canvas.clientHeight;
     parameters.screenWidth = canvas.width;
     parameters.screenHeight = canvas.height;
     gl.viewport( 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height );
    }
   }
 
   function animate() {
    resizeCanvas();
    render();
    requestAnimationFrame( animate );
   }
 
   function render() {
    if ( !currentProgram ) 
            return;
    parameters.time = new Date().getTime() - parameters.start_time;
    gl.clear( gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );
    gl.useProgram( currentProgram );
    gl.uniform1f( timeLocation, parameters.time / 1000 );
    gl.uniform2f( resolutionLocation, parameters.screenWidth, parameters.screenHeight );
    gl.bindBuffer( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer );
    gl.vertexAttribPointer( vertex_position, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0 );
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray( vertex_position );
    gl.drawArrays( gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 6 );
    gl.disableVertexAttribArray( vertex_position );
   }
```

```css
html, body {
  background-color: #000000;
  margin: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
canvas {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
<div id="info"></div> 

<script id="vs" type="x-shader/vertex"> 
  attribute vec3 position;
  
  void main() {
    gl_Position = vec4( position, 1.0 );
  }
</script> 

<script id="fs" type="x-shader/fragment"> 
  uniform float time;
  uniform vec2 resolution;

  void main( void ) {
    vec2 position = - 1.0 + 2.0 * gl_FragCoord.xy / resolution.xy;
    float red = abs( sin( position.x * position.y + time / 5.0 ) );
    float green = abs( sin( position.x * position.y + time / 4.0 ) );
    float blue = abs( sin( position.x * position.y + time / 3.0 ) );
    gl_FragColor = vec4( red, green, blue, 1.0 );
  }
</script>
```

this code uses buffer with 6 vertices for render something like this:

[image: full screen quad]

> does this method has any advantages or not?

comparing to method, where we render one triangle (3 vertices) covering full screen like on this picture:

[image: full screen triangle]

```css
body{
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>

<script type='glsl/vertex'>
  attribute vec2 coords;
  
  void main(void) {
    gl_Position = vec4(coords.xy, 0.0, 1.0);
  }
</script>

<script type='glsl/fragment'>precision highp float;

   uniform vec4 mr;
   
   void main(void) {
     vec2 p = gl_FragCoord.xy;
     vec2 q = (p + p - mr.ba) / mr.b;
     for(int i = 0; i < 13; i++) {
          q = abs(q)/dot(q,q) -  mr.xy/mr.zw;
     }
     gl_FragColor = vec4(q, q.x/q.y, 1.0);
   }
</script>

<script>
  let canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
  canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
  canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
  let gl = canvas.getContext('webgl') || canvas.getContext('experimental-webgl');
  var h = gl.drawingBufferHeight;
  var w = gl.drawingBufferWidth;
  
  let pid = gl.createProgram();
  shader('glsl/vertex', gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
  shader('glsl/fragment', gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
  gl.linkProgram(pid);
  gl.useProgram(pid);

  let array = new Float32Array([-1,  3, -1, -1, 3, -1]);
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, gl.createBuffer());
  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, array, gl.STATIC_DRAW);

  let al = gl.getAttribLocation(pid, "coords");
  gl.vertexAttribPointer(al, 2 /*components per vertex */, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(al);
  
  let mr = gl.getUniformLocation(pid, 'mr');
  
  window.addEventListener('mousemove', draw);
  window.addEventListener('touchmove', draw);

  draw();

  function draw(e) {
    let ev = e && e.touches ? e.touches[0] : e;
    let x = ev ? ev.clientX : 250;
    let y = ev ? h - ev.clientY: 111;
    gl.uniform4f(mr, x, y, w, h);
    gl.viewport(0, 0, w, h);
    gl.clearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
    gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
  }

  function shader(name, type) {
    let src = [].slice.call(document.scripts).find(s => s.type === name).innerText;
    let sid = gl.createShader(type);
    gl.shaderSource(sid, src);
    gl.compileShader(sid);
    gl.attachShader(pid, sid);
  }
</script>
```

Comment: There is no important difference. You're drawing single screen quad anyway. It's entirely a preference. I'd argue it's normal to draw that you want to draw, not to rely on side effects. As an example I could draw circles and rectangles by drawing spheres and cylinders with an orthographic projection but I don't. If I want to draw a circle or a rectangle I provide data for a circle or a rectangle not a sphere and cylinder. Similarly if I want to draw a quad I give data for a quad. I'd argue the triangle method is just of way of being *tricky*. But it really doesn't matter. Do whatever you want.

Comment: @gman i think about pixels on edge of triangles, does gpu handles triangles separately or not, does rasterization invoked per triangle or per quad?

Comment: @rabbit76, not they are not drawn twice. That would be explicitly against the spec and would also make edges appear when blending is on. As for rasterization that's up to the driver and GPU. For example tiled GPUs bucket things into tiles and draw each tile separately. Rendering tiles is parallelized as just one example. Also depending on the GPU it's just going to clip the triangle into a quad and then subdivide the quad into 2 triangles. That would certainly be the simplest way to rasterize. Make the hardware do one thing fast (draw triangles) then turn everything into triangles.

Comment: @gman : Don't your comments sound like answers rather than just clarifications?

Comment: And here's me using a fan with 4 vertices to draw my ndc quad ;)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In both cases, every pixel on the screen will be rasterized once, but they will not necessarily only be shaded once. Using two triangles, you will be subject to [quad overshading](https://blog.selfshadow.com/2012/11/12/counting-quads/) along the diagonal; some pixels will be shaded even though they're outside of their triangle, as helper invocations for the 2×2 quads, then shaded again by the other triangle.

Using two triangles can also be [less efficient for caching](https://michaldrobot.com/2014/04/01/gcn-execution-patterns-in-full-screen-passes/), due to implementation details of how pixel shader invocations are packaged into SIMD work groups by the GPU—again, around the edge between the two triangles, you could end up with pixels close together in space being shaded farther apart in time, compared to what happens when using a single fullscreen triangle.

Michal Drobot, in the blog post linked in the previous paragraph, found a performance delta of about 8% between single-triangle and two-triangle fullscreen draws. That only applies to the specific hardware and shaders he was working with, but it demonstrates that these overshading and cache issues can lead to a measurable performance decrease.

Also note that the fullscreen triangle will not be clipped into a quad by the GPU. GPUs use [guard-band clipping](https://fgiesen.wordpress.com/2011/07/05/a-trip-through-the-graphics-pipeline-2011-part-5/), meaning that they don't clip offscreen geometry until the vertices are so far offscreen that numerical precision would be lost in the rasterizer (which is very far). In case of the fullscreen triangle, the rasterizer will process it as a single triangle and will simply not generate fragments for the offscreen parts of it.

In short, there's no downside to using a fullscreen triangle, and it could give you a minor performance bump, so I would prefer that over a fullscreen quad in all cases.

Comment: What about the fact that you can use an interpolated vertex attribute to get the screen uv in a quad vs having to compute it with gl_fragCoord with the triangle? Is interpolation in the rasterizer slower anyways?

Comment: @JackWhite You can use interpolated UVs perfectly well with the triangle. You just have to set them up correctly, e.g. setting the corners to (2, 0), (0, 2), and (0, 0) (or whatever is appropriate for your UV orientation). I doubt if it makes any difference for perf whether you use UVs or gl_FragCoord, but I haven't tested that.

Comment: Hadn't thought about the uv's for the triangle, that's neat! Thanks for the great answer(s)!